# The element link didn't redirect to its target page?

Tags: java, android, html, webview, hyperlink

Hello everyone for testing Purposes
I tried to copy the InnerHtml of "facebook create new account button", and then load it on webview1

`<a href="/reg/?cid=102&amp;refid=8&amp;__ccr=ARb4C00_1i5sbm8nG9JpVEMPOtl8ePPi5qdUl8f06_X9aJ_6" class="m n o p q s"><span class="t">Create Account</span></a>`

But after I click the create new account button, the webview becomes all white.

I dont know  the exact phrase of this question
Please edit my question so I can find the exact keyord on google search and also
Please edit my grammar
Thank you

Comment: is it because in the href there isn't any reference to facebook.com, just /reg/?cid... etc

Answer (score 0):

In links you don't need to use `&amp;` you can just use the ampersand as it is.